# What is the time complexity of collecting a stream in Java, with no intermediate operations?

Tags: java, java-stream, time-complexity, big-o, collectors

I'm trying to find out if simply collecting a stream into a list, set etc. actually iterates over the stream. I expect it does in O(n) time.

Comment: Yes. It is impossible to add the elements to a list without iterating them.

Comment: This question is a bit ambiguous. The stream itself could be `sorted()`, in which case collecting (which involves consuming the stream) would be O(n log n) because non-terminal stream operations like `sorted()` are lazy, so the actual sorting would happen when the `collect()` method is invoked. But if you define the sorting as a separate operation that takes O(n log n) time, and only count the time complexity of actually creating and populating the list, then it's O(n).

Comment: Thanks. To make it less ambiguous, the context is that I have some code that runs on every write and collects the stream, so I thought it might be costly

Comment: Collecting into a list can never be better than O(n), however, processing a stream doesn’t mean “iterating over a stream”, as a stream doesn’t store the elements. Processing the stream implies “iterating over the source” and depends on the source. Typically, sources can be iterated in O(n), which makes the overall time complexity O(n). But to name a counter example, `Stream.iterate(BigInteger.ONE, condition, bi -> bi.add(BigInteger.ONE))` is not O(n) (for an arbitrary condition).

Answer (score 1):

> What is the time complexity of collecting a stream in Java, with no
> intermediate operations?

In Java, if you are collecting a `stream` without no intermediate operations, the `stream` is traversed once to create the final `collection`. The time complexity of collecting a `stream` in such case is `O(n)`, where `n` represents the size of the stream.

> I'm trying to find out if simply collecting a stream into a list, set
> etc. actually iterates over the stream. I expect it does in O(n) time.

It is correct to say that when you are collecting a `stream` into a `list`, `set`, or `any other collections` in Java, it is necessary to iterate over the `stream` once to create the final `collection`. It means that the time complexity of the operation is `O(n)`, where `n` represents the size of the `stream`. The reason is that each element in the `stream` must be processed once to add it to the final `collection`.

Answer (score 0):

To quote from the documentation of Java's [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html):

> A sequential implementation of a reduction using a collector would create a single result container using the supplier function, and invoke the accumulator function once for each input element. A parallel implementation would partition the input, create a result container for each partition, accumulate the contents of each partition into a subresult for that partition, and then use the combiner function to merge the subresults into a combined result.

So for the trivial, sequential case you would see exactly what you'd expect: the `Collector` generating a result container, iterating over the elements from the stream and calling the accumulator()-function on it (e.g. `ArrayList::add`). This would turn out to be O(n)-complexity.

For the parallel case the complexity would be complicated by the need to run the `combiner()`-method to merge intermediate results. (I don't know how to calculate the time complexity for that off the top of my head, tbqh.)